# Why is TopAppBar navigationIcon's not a composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, android-compose-appbar

My IDE is showing that navigationIcon  is not a composable function. Other people are doing the same thing. I'm getting this error

```
@composable invocations can only happen from the context of an @composable function
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppBar(onClick: () -> Unit){
    TopAppBar(
        title = "Princess World", 
        navigationIcon = { 
            IconButton(onClick = onClick) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = null)
            } 
        },
    ) {}
}
```

I'm unable to use composable functions inside of title and navigation icon {}

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppBar(onClick: () -> Unit){
   TopAppBar(title = { }, navigationIcon = { }) {

   }
}
```

Comment: You might consider editing your question and posting which specific `TopAppBar()` function signature you are calling. Not only are there several `TopAppBar()` functions, but there are many versions of Compose.

Comment: There are 2 and only one with navigationIcon as a parameter. Secondly, all software has many versions. I'm not posting a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the final `{}`:

```
TopAppBar(
    title = { Text("Princess World") },
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = onClick) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = null)
        }
    }
)
```

Using the `{}` you are trying to use the constructor with the attribute `content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit` that doesn't have the `title` and the `navigationIcon` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are 2 TopAppBar composable that you have to invoke properly with their corresponding parameters.

This one,

```
@Composable
fun AppBar(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text (text = "Princess World") },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = onClick) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
    ) 
}
```

calling this one from the API,

```
@Composable
    fun TopAppBar(
        title: @Composable () -> Unit,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        navigationIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
        actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
        backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
        contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
        elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation
    ) { … }
```

or this one,

```
TopAppBar {

}
```

calling this from the API

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = AppBarDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) { … }
```

Comment: I'm using the one with navigationIcon as the parameter. The second one doesn't have this. That doesn't work.